# How many nodes can be managed by Rundeck Community edition?

Tags: chef-infra, rundeck, knife

With the EOL for push-jobs, for newer releases of Chef (Chef-Infra, Chef-Client, Chef-workstation), it has become difficult to manage the Chef nodes from chef workstation. Using knife ssh maybe an ideal option but not the most convincing approach.

Wanted to integrate Rundeck to this and try the approach. However, was not able to find out how many nodes can be managed by Rundeck Community edition.

Can anyone let me know the number of nodes that can be remotely managed by Rundeck's Community edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically and officially no limits for that, it all depends on your instance [resources](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/tuning-rundeck.html#tuning-rundeck).